# About Apache DirecrtoryIndex Setting

Tags: apache

I have two apache servers,  X and Y. They have the same index.php file. I do some experiment.

First I send URL / to each other, I got the same response "ABCD"("ABCD" is echo by index.php.) from X and Y.

I think Apache DirectoryIndex setting is fine.

Second I Send URL/string to each other. X got "ABCD", but Y got "Not Found
The requested URL /string was not found on this server.".

Both X and Y do not have .htaccess file. And I check apache2.conf, sites-enabled are same.

My question is why server X and Y have such a difference?

Please help, thanks a lot.

Comment: It isn't correctly spelt: you want `DirectoryIndex` not `DirecrtryIndex` [[ref](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex)]. Also, the directive does not do what you probably think.

Comment: Thanks Álvaro González, I fix the wrong spelt. But there is something difference between two LAMP Server setting.

Comment: Well, sorry, I don't really have the faintest idea of what you're doing and how it fails for you (how do you send URLs between servers?). I had the impression that you were expecting some URL rewriting but, honestly, I don't know.